# LInq update is also inserting unwanted rows

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am new to Linq to SQL, but I am surprised at the problems I am having updating a table.
From reading various sources I think the problem I get is a problem with the ORM mapping, but even so, given I am using VS 2008 and creating my dbml via a LINQ to SQL class, I do not expect this.
So what is happening is that when I update and/or insert a row, lots of other rows get created in the table as well. I cannot predict what the pattern is when this happens, sometimes it doesn't happen.
I am not sure the code below says very much about what the problem is, but I reproduce it here;

```
    public static void UpdateDailyTimeRecorded(
        int dailyTimeRecordedId, bool amFlag, string timeIn, string timeOut)
    {
        DailyTimeRecorded dtr = GetDailyTimeRecorded(dailyTimeRecordedId);
        if (amFlag == true)
        {
            dtr.MorningTimeIn_HH = Convert.ToInt32(timeIn.Substring(0, 2));
            dtr.MorningTimeIn_MM = Convert.ToInt32(timeIn.Substring(3, 2));
            dtr.MorningTimeOut_HH = Convert.ToInt32(timeOut.Substring(0, 2));
            dtr.MorningTimeOut_MM = Convert.ToInt32(timeOut.Substring(3, 2));
            dtr.MorningLeaveFlagId = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            dtr.AfternoonTimeIn_HH = Convert.ToInt32(timeIn.Substring(0, 2));
            dtr.AfternoonTimeIn_MM = Convert.ToInt32(timeIn.Substring(3, 2));
            dtr.AfternoonTimeOut_HH = Convert.ToInt32(timeOut.Substring(0, 2));
            dtr.AfternoonTimeOut_MM = Convert.ToInt32(timeOut.Substring(3, 2));
            dtr.AfternoonLeaveFlagId = 0;
        }
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (ChangeConflictException)
        {
            db.ChangeConflicts.ResolveAll(RefreshMode.KeepChanges);
        }
    }
```

I put a breakpoint on the line db.SubmitChanges(); and the rows get inserted at this point for sure, not before and not some code afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `DataContext.GetChanges()` and see what else is captured. It might be from a previous 'non-committed' action on the data context.

Comment: It is indeed. I have 20 inserts. 
No doubt the reason why is because my DataContext field is stored as follows;
public static FWHDataContext db = new FWHDataContext();
I put in the folowing code;
            ChangeSet cs = db.GetChangeSet();
            db.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Clear();
            cs = db.GetChangeSet();
Initially to put in breakpoints and see what was happening.
HOwever clearing the inserts had unexpected knock on effects. What is the optimal solution for this?

Comment: Why is the DataContext static?  This seems dangerous.  DataContexts are designed to be lightweight so you can create them wherever you need.  It's better to create and destroy them a bunch of times than to keep one lying around for everything.

Comment: You are right it should not be static.
I have changed that now.

Answer (score 2):

One cause that I'm aware of off the top of my head that might cause LINQ to insert unexpected data is this.  Even though you don't explicitly add a row of data to a particular table, LINQ to SQL will implicitly add it if you have it linked to another object that you *have* explicitly added.

Another cause is that you cannot readily rollback or undo pending changes added to a context.  My understanding is that the best practice is to dispose of the context containing the unwanted objects and start a new one if and when you realize that you didn't want to perform the update.

Comment: This is helpful.
I now understand DataContext much better now.

Comment: How do we compete with the first reason ? i have no choice I must insert new object that contains other linked objects(entitiyref) , due to foreign keys relationships